# D: Cannot seem to create an std.container.Array of const struct pointers

Tags: pointers, d, const-correctness, phobos

Suppose I have a struct type `Foo`. I'm trying to create an `std.container.Array` of const pointers to `Foo`. I tried the obvious first:

```
import std.container;

alias FooArray = Array!(const(Foo*));
```

However, this causes a compiler error. Then I tried it with fewer parentheses:

```
alias FooArray = Array!(const Foo*);
```

But this gave the same error (`error instantiating` apparently). What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array` probably needs to modify the reference (if not the object).

Try this:

```
alias FooArray = Array!(const(Foo)*);
```